# Ansible: Conditional "when" clause with empty variable

Tags: ansible

I am tasked with creating an Ansible role, where I set a variable within the *defaults/main.yml* file in the same role.

`role_variable: ""`

This variable is then recalled within another task, which uses it as conditional, in order to perform operations:

**ROLE**

```
-name: "Task which is called" 
   # Stuff which will be done given that the conditional below is correct
   set_fact:
      role_variable: "{{ variable_1 if 'string' not in issuer else variable_2 }} "
 when: (role_variable | length == 0)
```

Within the playbook, this variable is not ***set*** anywhere else -it is only used for debug- and if I print the above condition within a `debug` clause, it correctly returns `0`.

**PLAYBOOK**

```
-name: "Import secrets" 
   vars_files: 
     - secrets.yml
hosts: "{{ target }}"
gather_facts: false

tasks:
   - include_vars:
      file: "{{ credentials }}"
   - ansible.builtin.setup:
     gather_subset: min ### This is used in other parts of the complete playbook
   delegate_to: localhost

   - name: "Task to call"
      import_role: 
         name: role_name
         tasks_from: role_task_name
```

When this variable is not set a value within the playbook, it evaluates correctly, e.g. :
`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e ""`

But whenever this is evaluated even with an empty string (e.g.):

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e "role_variable="`

This is necessary for example within Jenkins builds, where this variable can either be passed or not by the user. If not, it should use a default, scripted within the role or play.

I have tried additional methods of doing the same thing:

`when: role_variable is none`

`when: role_variable is null`

`when: role_variable is none`

`when: role_variable is match("")`

So far, I had no luck.

The objective is to pass the `role_variable` as default with an empty string `""`, and re-set it only if such variable is empty.

Does anybody have any past experiences with this, on how it is possible to make this work?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: [I can't reproduce (or understand) your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/d251c8f512fd2d3e139b1f0de1206850)

Comment: Thanks zeitounator. You reproduced the environment correctly, we also have the same version of Jinja. It looks like we have 2 different behaviours... I cannot figure out why.

Comment: It seems that if I try to print a message with the same condition, it is correctly set, but if I try to add a `set_facts`, trying to set the same `role_variable` if it's empty, then the operation is not being made. Any clues?

Comment: [I still can't reproduce](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/d251c8f512fd2d3e139b1f0de1206850)

Comment: Just to rule out a possible misunderstanding: `--extra_vars / -e` have the highest precedence and always win. Said differently, you cannot override the value of an extra var by any mean (host/group var, role var, role default, playbook var, set_fact....) during playbook execution.

Comment: Thanks zeitounator. It seems an odd behavior, but I perfectly understand that this is by-design.

In short - there should be no way to override a default variable if it has not been set previously: that is, if it is not included in the `extra vars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified - also thanks to the guys who contributed - that what I am trying to achieve is in fact not possible.

According to [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), setting the variable with the `--extra-vars` or `-e` flag takes precedence in setting the variable.

Even the single act of defining it, and leaving it as empty, just triggers the condition, and it is not possible to override it.

In my case, since I have to pass it to Jenkins via a .groovy file, I have set up a condition where I instruct when variable is empty, it doesn't pass the argument.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this test:

```
- name: "Task which is called" 
  debug: msg="ok"
  when: role_variable is not defined or role_variable == ''
```

you'll see the task executed if role_variable is not defined or role_variable is empty

for your problem

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:   
    - name: loop over
      pause: 
        prompt: "role_variable is empty, give the content " 
      when: role_variable is not defined or role_variable == ''
      register: out

    - name: "Task which is called" 
      set_fact:
        role_variable: "{{ out.user_input }}"
      when: out.user_input is defined

    - name: display
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ role_variable }}"
```

but it seems the result is empty...when launching `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e "role_variable="`  i dunno if its bug

Comment: Thanks Frenchy. I just tried, but it looks like this test doesn't work for my case. I also tried putting parentheses, but no luck again.

Comment: i dont see why  have you an old version of ansible?, you could try to surround the whole expression by `"` and what is your error?

Comment: Ansible version is "ansible core 2.12.3" - I don't have any errors, I'm just trying to print the string, but it just returns "", as if the variable wouldn't be re-set within the above condition.

Comment: sorry but could you show your playbook in the question, your error seems to be there, have you tested just my task?

Comment: No worries, I have edited the question with an indication of the playbook that I'm using. I am just modifying the parts within the role task in order to test it.

Comment: i dont see in the playbook where the var role_variable is setted when is empty?

Comment: It is set in the main.yml file within the defaults folder in the role

Comment: ok but if you set it from command ansible-playbook, this value overrides the default value.. and you have to do a reset_fact to reset the var or do a pause with prompt

Comment: Thinking about it - the behaviour is correct, but if i evaluate it with an empty parameter (see example above), shouldn't the when clause interpret it with length == 0 (true) and just carry on with the operations within the "when"?

Comment: it seems a var defined in command ansible-playbook couldnt be changed..i dunno if its bug...